# Reloading current user doesn't refresh emailVerified state in Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to fix the problem for a whole day and couldn't make it work. I'm getting irritated, firebase docs are such a mess it's insane..

So I'm trying to implement email verification on my React app. I wen't with the docs, and google do send the email, I can click it, it's all good.
But, the email verified state doesn't change at all, and believe me I've went through all the stackoverflow topics.

```
firebase.auth().doSignInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => {
            console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser);
            firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()
                .then(() => {
                    console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser);
                })
        })
```

So I've found i need to reload the user to see the changes applied, tho they just won't work no matter what I do.
Both console logs return `email.verified = false` at all times.
I'm hopeless, anyone have any idea on how to make this work?
I was wondering whether me setting up custom domain as a verification link has to do anything with that? I'm testing on localhost, link is linking to live website.
Please help :(

Comment: Are you sending the verification link, clicking it and processing (calling `applyActionCode`) it in your custom landing page before you `reload()` the currentUser?

Comment: I'm not calling `applyActionCode` anywhere.
Are you saying I need to extract the code from URL and call that function?

Comment: Yes, if you are building your custom landing page and not using the default one. Learn more about this from the official docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Answer (score 7):

The method you should call is `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, so remove the "do" in the function call:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((credential) => {
            const currentUser = credential.user;
            console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser);
            firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()
                .then(() => {
                    console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser);
                })
        }).catch((err) => {console.error("Problem with sign in ", err);}
```

Use the `credential` returned from this function and assign its `user` value to `currentUser` to validate that the user has been authenticated.

Lastly, remember to add a `catch` at the end whenever you use `then`. In this case, `err` will contain a property `err.code` that will tell you why the user could not be authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You need to reload your current user using a timer and then listen to user changes (not auth changes) in a Streambuilder. As soon as the user clicks the link they will be redirected to your main page.

Use a Streambuilder to listen to changes to the user:

```
  StreamBuilder<User?>(
     stream: FirebaseAuth.instance
        .userChanges(), // monitor the changes to the user
     builder: (ctx, snapshot) {

      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
        return LoadingScreen(); // show loading screen while loading
     
     if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.emailVerified) {
        return VerifyEmailScreen();
      }  // if not verified show the verify email screen
      
     
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return MainScreen();
      } // if logged in already show main screen

      return OnboardingScreen(); // if not logged in already show the auth screen
    },
  ),
```

In your VerifyEmailScreen() create a timer in it's initState like this:

```
  void initState() {

    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.reload();
    });

   super.initState();
  }
```

I hope it helps your problem.
Cheers